# Error en la linea de codigo 10, 17 y 27 en Lua Roblox Studio, no se que pasa que me tira error

Tags: lua

Estoy Haciendo un script para roblox studio en lua y nose por que me tira error en las lineas 10, 17 y 27. lo que intente hacer en este script era que cuando apriete un objeto que era un horno, se prenda una sarten y que despues de 20 segundos la sarten empieze a hervir el agua y si apago el horno, pasan 10 segundos y se deja de hervir el agua y ademas de esto tambien hace que un objeto que se llama fuego aparezca con la propiedad de transparency. ademas me tira lineas azules que tampoco se por que me salen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca tienen el codigo:

```html
local Horno = workspace.Horno
local Fuego = workspace.Fire
local Sonido = workspace.Fire.Sound
local ActivadordeHorno = workspace.Horno.ClickDetector
local Aguadelasarten = workspace["Kitchen pan with water"].Water
local vapor = workspace["Kitchen pan with water"]["Boiling Water"].ParticleEmitter
local burbujeo = workspace["Kitchen pan with water"]["Boiling Water"].Sound

local function encendedordehorno()
    if ActivadordeHorno.MouseClick and Fuego.Transparency = 1 and Sonido.Playing = false then
        Fuego.Transparency = 0
        Sonido.Playing = true
        Sonido.Looped = true
        wait(20)
        vapor.Enabled = true
        burbujeo.Playing = true
    elseif ActivadordeHorno.MouseClick and Fuego.Transparency = 0 and Sonido.Playing = true then
        Fuego.Transparency = 1
        Sonido.Playing = false
        Sonido.Looped = false
        wait(10)
        vapor.Enabled = false
        burbujeo.Playing = false
    end
end

ActivadordeHorno.MouseClick:Connect.(encendedordehorno)
```

Answer (score 0):

En las condiciones if, debes usar el operador de igualdad (==) para comparar valores, no el operador de asignación (=).

Hay un error en la sintaxis de llamada de función para el evento MouseClick. El punto (.) debe eliminarse después de Conectar.

La variable burbujeo está indexada con un nombre de propiedad incorrecto (Reproduciendo), que debería ser SoundId en su lugar.

Te dejo por aquí el código corregido:

```
local Horno = workspace.Horno
local Fuego = workspace.Fire
local Sonido = workspace.Fire.Sound
local ActivadordeHorno = workspace.Horno.ClickDetector
local Aguadelasarten = workspace["Kitchen pan with water"].Water
local vapor = workspace["Kitchen pan with water"]["Boiling Water"].ParticleEmitter
local burbujeo = workspace["Kitchen pan with water"]["Boiling Water"].Sound

local function encendedordehorno()
    if ActivadordeHorno.MouseClick and Fuego.Transparency == 1 and not Sonido.Playing then
        Fuego.Transparency = 0
        Sonido.Playing = true
        Sonido.Looped = true
        wait(20)
        vapor.Enabled = true
        burbujeo.SoundId = "INSERT_SOUND_ID" 
        burbujeo.Playing = true
    elseif ActivadordeHorno.MouseClick and Fuego.Transparency == 0 and Sonido.Playing then
        Fuego.Transparency = 1
        Sonido.Playing = false
        Sonido.Looped = false
        wait(10)
        vapor.Enabled = false
        burbujeo.Playing = false
    end
end

ActivadordeHorno.MouseClick:Connect(encendedordehorno) -- quitado el punto despues de connect
```